# DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY environement variables missing in the systemd user environment list

Tags: 20.04, systemd

I m not able to run graphical application as systemd service in user mode because the DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY variable are missing in the result of : `systemctl --user show-environment`.

How can add these variable so that they appear in the list and my user service can make use of it.

Comment: You do not want to run graphical applications as a systemd service. Instead of asking about how you think you can do this (Problem *Y*), ask about how you could achieve what you want (your real problem *X*). Then people can come up with adapted direct help.

Comment: So it appears you aready got help on Problem X, but you seem to persist: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474738/gui-application-fails-to-launch-as-a-systemd-servicedaemon-in-system-session Carefully read the answer there again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GUI application fails to launch as a systemd service(daemon) in system session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474738/gui-application-fails-to-launch-as-a-systemd-servicedaemon-in-system-session)

Comment: @vanadium From this answer I am aware that running GUI application via systemd service is not possible in system mode, but I m sure that it is possible in the user session(not recommended though), and hence my question.

Comment: You say it: not recommended though. So why would you try to do something that is not recommended, and that appears actually difficult to do, while other recommended approaches may be available?